# function_exported?/3 doesn't work as expected in escript

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'd like to use `Code.format_string!/2` of Elixir 1.6 in my escript code. For the compatibility between different Elixir versions, I planed to use `function_exported?/3` to see if format_string is supported in user's environment. But I found it doesn't work as expected. It always returns `false` in Macbook(Elixir is 1.6), but it can be called normally.

I created a demo to describe this problem:

https://github.com/tony612/escript_export

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`function_exported?/3` assumes the module is already loaded in memory. You probably want to do this:

```
if Code.ensure_loaded?(Code) and function_exported?(Code, :format_string!, 2) do
  ...
```